# how to autofocus native camera frame in android to A4 size frame

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

how to autofocus native camera in android to A4 size frame so through camera i can directully take photo of A4 size paper with below sizes in ixel

size of 
A4 in 72dpi = 595*842px

is it possible? in android

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Can you show us the code you used? and post some of the pictures you're getting?

Comment: my problem is i dont know how to autofocus directly to at perticular size say example a4 size

actually i want to capture an image through camera whoes focus is directly set to the a4 size paper

Answer (score 0):

You must get the parameters of the camera after opening the camera and then get parameters and set the picture size accordingly

```
camera = Camera.open();
Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
params.setPictureSize(495,842); //this sets the A4 size image
```

In case of using intent:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputX", 495);
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputY", 842);
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getTempUri());
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat",
                    Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Comment: #Rishabh
am using  Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

to capture the image through camera so where i can put ur code cause am opening camera through intent